# Send link to IDM

Tags: python

I use os.system() to run command line:

```
os.system(PathIDM + ' /d ' + URL)
```

but it throw a error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Quote the `PathIDM` so that the program path is recognised as whole instead of `C:\Program` part only:

```
os.system('"{}" /d {}'.format(PathIDM, URL))
```

or use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) instead:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([PathIDM, '/d', URL])
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by add double cote ( " ) before and after IDM path:

```
PathIDM = '"path\to\IDMan.exe"'
```